# How to create Visual Studio style class diagram in Visio?

Tags: asp.net, class, diagram, visio

I need to plan out a `Class`, `Method`, `Attribute` style diagram, I have looked at the `Class Designer` in `Visual Studio`, but it seems to not do what I want.
I want to be able to have a diagram show the classes just like in `Visual Studio` - except I want to be able to represent the parameters these methods require, for example:

```
getStock(StockID)
```

And this be shown in the Diagram. This is for an `ASP.NET` website - what are the best ways of creating a diagram for a website like this to represent the methods - I don't want to start generating classes - which is why I want to use `Visio`, plus I am more familiar with `Visio` than the `Visual Studio Class` designer as I mostly use the `Express` line of products which don't feature this.

I want this for example for `Default.aspx`:

```
Default.aspx
(View)

Methods:  
- FeaturedStock()  
- GetStock(StockID)  
- ShowContent()
- ShowImage(StockID)
```

I don't want to use `UML` as this is too confusing - the `Visual Studio Class` diagram is close to what I want but I cannot get it to show the Parameters on my Methods.

My main aim is to have "stubs" for each method a page requires to implement that functionality as a Developer this is the easiest way I can plan out this project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NClass](http://nclass.sourceforge.net/) was quite good the last time I used it. It's a UML tool, but a drag and drop GUI and not at all confusing. Plus, it will generate code if you want it to; you don't *have* to use it for that though.

Comment: That looks like an easier to use application, and seems a bit easier than the class designer in Visual Studio. I will check it out!

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate supports UML class diagrams, which will not generate code unless you want to:

[image]

Here's the reference topic: **[UML Class Diagrams: Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409437%28VS.100%29.aspx)**

I've posted more links on [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275715/esther-fan) for more info.

Comment: This seems fine - but I never really got into UML, and wanted something more like the Visual Studio class designer - just wanted something that would not create classes. It is useful however as if I do use UML I know it is supported in VS (which I did not know!)